# Normalizing data before applying MDS with strain criterion

Tags: matlab, normalization, multidimensional-scaling

The features of my dataset are like below:
`•  BI-RADS assessment:` 1 to 5 (ordinal)  
`•  Age:` patient's age in years (integer) ranges from 18 to 96
`•  Shape:` mass shape: round=1 oval=2 lobular=3 irregular=4 (nominal)
`•  Margin:` mass margin: circumscribed=1 microlobulated=2 obscured=3 ill-defined=4 spiculated=5 (nominal)
`•  Density:` mass density high=1 iso=2 low=3 fat-containing=4 (ordinal)

When I run `MDS` with `"strain"` criterion on such a dataset without normalizing it first, I get a result as follows:
[image]
However, if I normalize the data the result is as follows:
[image]
The second results is pretty similar to results that I have got for other criteria and also for the `PCA` even I didn't normalize the data for them also.

So, my question is: Why does normalizing data make difference for "strain" criterion?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your question seems to be MATLAB-specific. I think you ought to read the procedure's documentation thoroughly and then, if something remains strange, ask. Also, what type of normalization do you do and what is strain criterion - please describe.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you run 2 pieces of code and are unsure why they provide different results? In this case I recommend you to post the relevant code fragments as it is a bit unclear what you are doing exactly with the current information.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you don't normalize your data. You could have a situation like this:

```
    user1   user2   user3   user4   user5   user6   user7   user8   user9
1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
2   18      96      21      45      93      19      21      19      90
3   0.08    0.12    0.19    0.70    0.12    0.01    0.00    0.09    0.04
4   1019    217     53      1082    1010    2       30      0       100
```

So it is clear that some features influence the results much more than others.

Remember that the MDS is a way to force differences between elements in n dimensions in differences in 2 dimensions, **between all the couples of elements**! I simply think that in the first case the strain function

[image]

is affected by the lack of normalization.
When you normalize the data the algorithm is able to catch the real differences among the points considering in a proper way all the different features.